# Ignoring Files With Chokidar In Watched Folders

Tags: node.js, fs

I'm trying to ignore specific files within folders using Chokidar. I'm sure the syntax for the ignore path is incorrect, but I can't seem to find the problem. I've tried all combinations of strings, globs, and arrays. I'd appreciate if someone would point me in the right direction.

Here's a quick example of the problem. I'm trying to ignore `ignore.js`, but since the folder is being watched, `console.log` is executed when both writing and deleting the file.

```
    var chokidar = require('chokidar');
    var fs = require('fs');
    var path = require('path');

    var watcher = chokidar.watch('./test', {
      ignored: path.resolve('./test/ignore.js'), 
      persistent: true,
      ignoreInitial: true,
      alwaysState: true
    });

    watcher.on('all',console.log);

    setTimeout(function(){fs.writeFile('./test/ignore.js', 'w');}, 200);
    setTimeout(function(){fs.unlink('./test/ignore.js');}, 300);
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The docs for `chokidar` say "The whole path is tested", so perhaps you should do `__dirname + '/test/ignore.js'`? The "whole path" would probably not contain a `.`.

Comment: I had high hopes for your solution, but unfortunately it didn't work. I've updated the example with a `path.resolve` to include your suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am inclined to agree with @loganfsmyth's comment that your path name is wrong. In my app I dynamically lookup the folder chokidar is monitoring from a function. For instance

```
Meteor.methods({
      getWatchFolder: function () {
          return watchFolder;
      },
});
```

I set watchFolder elsewhere, it's not really important in the context of this question, but assume it is returning "/tmp". This worked great, and ignored that file:

```
var watcher = chokidar.watch(Meteor.call('getWatchFolder'), {
  ignored: path.resolve(Meteor.call('getWatchFolder')+'/ignore.js'), 
  persistent: true
});
```

I noticed this only ignored /tmp/ignore.js, not a nested instance like /tmp/tmp2/ignore.js. If you want to ignore all nested instances this is easily remedied by adding the double asterisk wildcard to the ignore path:

```
var watcher = chokidar.watch(Meteor.call('getWatchFolder'), {
  ignored: path.resolve(Meteor.call('getWatchFolder')+'/**/ignore.js'), 
  persistent: true
});
```

I tried setting my watch folder to . like you. It found TONS of files, I determined it was running from

```
/Users/esoyke/myAppName/.meteor/local/build/programs/server
```

This was not respecting my ignore path though. When I changed it from watching . to that absolute path instead, it naturally found the same files but the ignore worked again. I suspect there is an issue with absolute vs. relative paths going on here, see if you can refactor to use an absolute path.

P.S. Thanks for showing me that path.resolve, I hadn't used that Node module yet. I was trying to add multiple sub-directories to the ignore and was trying to do so by editing chokidar's default regex of /[/\]./. This approach is much simpler and easier to read. Sadly it doesn't seem like chokidar's library allows multiple ignore values at the moment, and path.resolve returns an array when there are more than one arg to it, so I'll probably have to go back to regex to get multiple ignore paths working.